# ion-view does not update when changing states

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a simple log in system in Ionic.  When I type in my credentials and hit log in it should take me to a settings screen.  It does so, but it doesn't update the header; it still says account - it should say settings.

Settings View:

```
 <ion-view view-title = "Settings">
         <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
            <button class="button button-full button-assertive" style = "margin-top: 0px;" ng-click = "signOff()">
              Log Off
            </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-content class="has-header padding">
            ...
            ...
            ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Account View:

```
 <ion-view view-title="Account">
             <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
                <button class="button button-full button-assertive" style = "margin-top: 0px;" ng-click = "signOff()">
                  Log Off
                </button>
              </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-content class = "padding">
            <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model = "userName">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" ng-model = "password">
          </label>

          <button style = "margin: 10px"; class="button button-positive"; ng-click = "logIn(userName, password)">
            Log in
          </button>

          <button style = "margin: 10px"; class="button button-positive"; ng-click = "createAccount(userName, password)">
            Create Account
          </button>

        </div>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" hidden="true">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

logIn Function:

```
  $scope.logIn = function(userName, password) {
    console.log(userName);
    console.log(password);
      $rootScope.ref.authWithPassword({
        email    : userName,
        password : password
      }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
          console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
          $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
          $state.go('tab.settings');
         // $window.location.href = "#/tab/settings";
        }
      });
  };
```

I've tried $window.location.href instead of $state.go and I've tried to use ion-nav-title inside of my ion-view but both still yields the same result...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced!

EDIT: It looks like it also uses the account controller instead of the settings controller.

Comment: It would be really easier to help you if you could set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io/), a [plunker](http://plnkr.co) or any other playground in a minimal example reproducing your problem. So we would be sure to have the relevant piece of code. For example one important piece is missing: the `$state` configuration

Comment: But it could also be as simple as doing `$state.go('tab.settings', {}, { reload: true });` instead of just `$state.go('tab.settings');`

Comment: This magically started to work actually - i'm not sure what I did to get it to work but now its working...Thanks.

Comment: Ha ok. Glad to hear it. In case you figure it out you could always post an answer here if you think it may help further readers